# How Do You Use Q.all In Non-Static Form?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, q

I'm writing a JavaScript API.  The API returns promises created with Kris Kowal's (& contributors') Q promises library.  For the most part, I seem to be able to not have to refer to Q in the application itself, which I like because it makes my choice of Promises-library transparent to the person who develops with my API.  The only method that I seem to be having trouble (so far) is [Q.all()](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall).

The Q API Reference states "This method is often used in its static form".  Is it possible to use Q.all() in a non-static form (or otherwise) so that I don't need to refer to Q?

For example to fetch people and jobs in series (I don't want series.  made-up example):

```
MyApplication.prototype.renderTeam = function(name) {

  var that = this;

  myAPI
    .getTeam({name: name})
    .then(function(data) {
      that.team = data;
    })

    // list of all people
    .then(function() {
      return myAPI.getPeople();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      that.people = data;
    })

    // list of all jobs
    .then(function(data) {
      return myAPI.getJobs();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      that.jobs = data;
    })

    // render template
    .then(function() {
      var template = $('#template'}.html();
      var content = Mustache.render(template, {
        team: that.team,
        people: that.people,
        jobs: that.jobs
      })
      $('#view').html(content);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
      alert(err.message);
    })
  ;
};
```

I would like to fetch all people and jobs in parallel with .all and .spread (or any other way), but without referring to Q, but this doesn't work:

```
MyApplication.prototype.renderTeam = function(name) {

  var that = this;

  myAPI
    .getTeam({name: name})
    .then(function(data) {
      that.team = data;
    })

    // list of all people and jobs.
    // broken here.
    .all([
      myAPI.getPeople(),
      myAPI.getJobs()
    ])
    .spread(function(people, jobs) {
      that.people = people;
      that.jobs = jobs;
    })

    // render template
    .then(function() {
      var template = $('#template'}.html();
      var content = Mustache.render(template, {
        team: that.team,
        people: that.people,
        jobs: that.jobs
      })
      $('#view').html(content);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
      alert(err.message);
    })
  ;
};
```

Is there a correct way to accomplish this?  Do I have to add an API method getAll()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  myAPI
    .getTeam({name: name})
    .then(function(data) {
      that.team = data;
      return [
        myAPI.getPeople(),
        myAPI.getJobs()
      ];
    })
    .all()
    .spread(function(people, jobs) {
      that.people = people;
      that.jobs = jobs;
    })
```

Comment: lol, congrats on accept. well deserved for answer that explains a lot and uses `.all` correctly :D

Comment: Thank you!  That works for me:  No "Q" anywhere in this code.  And thanks to comment by @benjamin-gruenbaum, I was even able to drop the .all() completely, relying just .spread().

Answer (score 1):

Promises are all about chaining values. Writing a non static `all` like you ask for doesn't make a lot of sense in this context*. What are you chaining here? How are you using the value? and most importantly? How would JS not evaluate that code immediately given it's not in a function but in the outermost scope?

This makes non-static `.all` without a function argument impossible for what you want to accomplish. The documentation is simply a bit inaccurate here. The correct way to write what you wish for is:

```
 myAPI
    .getTeam({name: name})
    .then(function(data) {
      that.team = data;
      return Q.all([
        myAPI.getPeople(),
        myAPI.getJobs()]);
    ])
    .spread(function(people, jobs) {
      that.people = people;
      that.jobs = jobs;
    })
```

<sup>*The non static version of `all` present in other newer libraries like Bluebird does something rather different (ensures order in some operations like `.map`)</sup>

Comment: Q .all and bluebird .all do the same thing

Comment: @Esailija doesn't bluebird have a non-static variant?

Comment: yes both have static and instance .all, instance .all is useful in for example `.all().call("some", function(){})`

Comment: @Esailija go ahead and write an answer.

Comment: it's same as yours oops

Comment: @Esailija not on that.... on why it's useful to have non-static `.all` -_- that's what OP is asking about.

Comment: Edited my answer to use instance .all

Comment: Cool, have a +1, although I'd never write that code that way, and also, the `.all` is pointless because of the spread :P

Comment: I'm curious, Benjamin.  You said you'd never write code that way.  How would you have written it?

Comment: Because the `.all` is less explicit than in its static form, you don't have an immediately resolved promise on an array that you suddenly wait for each array element to resolve on, you have an array of promises you wait for.